# How to suppress piped input sent to perl on command line?

Tags: perl, pipe

At my comand prompt, I ran a grep and got the following result.

```
$ grep -r "javascript node" 

restexample/NewsSearchService/V1/madonna_html.html:<!-- start empty javascript node for popup app fix -->
restexample/NewsSearchService/V1/madonna_html.html:<!-- end empty javascript node for popup app fix -->
```

Now, suppose I want to remove the "`restexample`" part. I can do that by using

```
print substr($_,13)
```

However, how when I pipe to perl, this is what I get -

```
grep -r "javascript node" | perl -pe ' print substr($_,11) ' 
/NewsSearchService/V1/madonna_html.html:<!-- start empty javascript node for popup app fix -->
restexample/NewsSearchService/V1/madonna_html.html:<!-- start empty javascript node for popup app fix -->
/NewsSearchService/V1/madonna_html.html:<!-- end empty javascript node for popup app fix -->
restexample/NewsSearchService/V1/madonna_html.html:<!-- end empty javascript node for popup app fix -->
```

As you can see, the piped input simply got echoed. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
grep -r "javascript node" | perl -lpe '$_ = substr($_,11)'
```

or

```
grep -r "javascript node" | perl -lne 'print substr($_,11)'
```

Explanation: `-p` switch automatically prints current line (`$_`) while `-n` switch doesn't.

```
perl -MO=Deparse -lpe '$_ = substr($_,11)'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    $_ = substr($_, 11);
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_; # <<< automatic print
}
```

Comment: In the first command, perl isn't printing anything, yet we see the sub-string printed. Why?